# Vertical align a Row bootstrap Full Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sell</a></div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div></div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12"><div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Buy</a></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok so iam wanting the 2 buttons next to eachother as they are but want them both in the middle of the screen (Vertically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try setting the columns text-align left and right like this:
This will make 2 columns and format the left column as text-right and the right column as text left, which will bring them together in the center of the screen:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
         <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sell</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
          <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much that is a lot better way to do things i was wondering if you could also help me try center the 2 buttons in the middle of the page vertically for example vertical-align

Comment: Hey you are welcome - please don't forget to mark the answer as correct though.

You can vertically center the row my just giving it a margin-top: 45% or whatever. Other methods include using: positioning: absolute; top: 45% to the container.

Comment: Thanks so much am new at this XD

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182661/2145076) refference, you can check this out:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">

      <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sell</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Buy</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGmagX